# How to add git-repo to the the application and sync it?

Tags: git

I have one application (i.e app1) with proper git-setup in it. And I have the same application (i.e app2) with no git. That application is having all the latest changes. Now I want to add git to app2 and then want to update app1. How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, good question. Ain't sure but something like this should do the trick:

1. First, make a backup of `app2` :-)
2. `cd app2`
3. `mkdir tmp`
4. `cd tmp`
5. `git clone git://.../app1.git`
6. `git mv .git ..`
7. `cd ..`
8. Delete directory `tmp`
9. `git status`

Always try to keep your code under version control. Git has quite a small fingerprint.

Comment: Glad to hear, be careful next time.